# Any resource for image acquisition with industrial cameras in .NET?

Tags: c#, c++, camera

I know many people have tried to connect web cam with their program in .NET but surprisingly I couldn't find good material for image acquisition with industrial camera such as AVT cameras in .NET.

Most of SDK from camera manufacturer provides with C++ sample code but I would like to create a C# application. I guess I will eventually have to use interop between C# and C++ but still it will be nice to know what other programmers have previously done.

Comment: Pretty broad.  You might have better luck posting some C++ and asking how to do the equivalent in C#.

Comment: @AustinSalonen I agree with you but I hoped I can get more info than interop between C++ & C#.